# When using Ubuntu on a Live CD or USB, how can I determine if a different, inactive install is 32 vs 64 bit?

Tags: 64-bit, live-cd, live-usb, 32-bit, live-environment

I was not able to determine by searching whether this question has already been asked and answered. My search always turned up some other 32 versus 64 bit question.

I want to know if it is possible to determine whether an inactive Ubuntu install, that is, on a drive you did **not** boot from, is the 32-bit or 64-bit version. I cannot use `uname -m` because the Ubuntu I want to know about is *not* the Ubuntu which is running.

For example, if Ubuntu is installed on the hard drive of a desktop PC and the PC is booted from a Live CD/USB version of Ubuntu is it possible to tell what is installed on the hard drive just by looking at the file system of the Ubuntu on the hard drive?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Mount the partition where Ubuntu is installed on and run this command:

```
file /media/ubuntu-disk/sbin/init
```

*Where **/media/ubuntu-disk** is the path to where Ubuntu is mounted...*